# How can I prevent someone from logging in if they are not (for example) registered?

Tags: django

I'm using `django.contrib.auth.views.login`, but I want to stop users from being able to log in if a flag is set on them - for example, they haven't completed registration.

How could I go about that?

So far I only have ideas for nasty hacks that check *after* django.contrib.auth.views.login has logged them in, and log them out again before redirecting, which is really not on.

Comment: You could have a activatedAccount field, in the database default set to 0. And then they have to activate the account by clickin a link, that the server will send by email.

Comment: active field already exists, use it as a flag

Comment: Yes - I have this field - the question is how do I make the django login process refuse to log the person in if this field is not True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_active` is good choice but i ll do my custom field status `( default = 0 )`. After registration `if user:` then i ll `send mail` for activation link. If user click registration link i will change the status to 1.

I will check this status via `( from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm ) .`

**Updated:**

Okay I assumed that you are using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` for authentication. In this case you can use `AuthenticationForm`

*urls.py*

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', authentication_form:PickyAuthenticationForm),
```

*forms.py*

```
class PickyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if user.is_active:
            profileObj = Profile.objects.filter(pk=user.id)
            if profileObj.status == 1:
                print('welcome new user')
                pass
            else:
                print('Please verify email')
```

Comment: I have a similar "custom field" place.  What I don't yet see is how to make AuthenticationForm check it's status before letting someone log in...  that's what my question is asking.

Comment: I updated my answer.. It may help you .. let me know. .

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you know that AuthenticationForm has this method to override?

Comment: If you find my answer useful and appropriate for the question asked, please accept it. P.S (I came to know about this method through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend taking a look at the documentation for the `is_active` boolean field on the auth User model.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active

According to the docs, it's up to you (the developer) to implement the logic in your view or authentication backend to determine whether or not to authenticate a user using the `is_active` field as a flag.  But since you are using the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` view, the default form `AuthenticationForm` does the checking against the `is_active` flag for you and should return False when the `is_active` flag isn't set.